# Weird behaviour in Firestore querying with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Is there some kind of query caching in Firestore?

Say I have one component with this OnInit query:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.afs.collection('user_previews', ref => {
   return ref.where('location', '==', 'bar')
 })
  .valueChanges()
  .first()
  .subscribe(snap => console.log(snap));
}
```

This returns a correct array of UserPreviews, so far, so good.

Then, another completely different component in the site does another query:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.afs.collection('user_previews', ref => ref.where('id', '==', 'foo'))
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(snap => console.log(snap));
  }
```

This returns its own data from the same collection through a different query. The data is also ok.

Then the weird behaviour happens... When I navigate back to the first component, its query returned data is always the one the second component returns. These components are not siblings or communicated in any way.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue. In my case, the data result from 1st query is cached and when 2nd query is fired it filters result set retrieved via 1st query.

Have you managed to get solution for this?

Comment: I ended up using a dummy query every time this issue showed up as a workaround

Comment: I'd be really thankful if you can show me a small code snippet of the same...